# How to set default to ruby 2.1.2?

Tags: 12.04, ruby, rails

I have ruby 1.9.3 and 2.1.2. When I open the terminal by default it uses ruby 1.9.3 but I want to use ruby 2.1.2.

How can I set ruby 2.1.2 to be default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should install [RVM](http://rvm.io/) to manage your Ruby versions. 
To install RVM do

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev gawk libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev nodejs
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

If that breaks for some reason then follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/2376036

Then to make the default 2.1.2 do

```
rvm --default use 2.1.2
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your kind help, Yes, I followed your instructions but in the terminal while installing rvm it says "broken rvm package please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756" so I followed the path and get it to success, Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark my answer as accepted so that people in the future can know what worked for you. I will add the extra context from your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 19):

`/usr/bin/ruby` is usually a link to `/etc/alternatives/ruby`, which in turn links to the executable of the default ruby version (e. g. `/usr/bin/ruby1.9`). You can change the configured default version with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

If the desired version did not set up itself as alternative for `ruby` (e. g. if it isn't set up by the package manager), you can do it yourself with

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /path/to/ruby2.1 <PRIORITY>
```

where `<PRIORITY>` is a positive integer. Then you can perform the first step.

For details see the [manual of `update-alternatives(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-alternatives.8.html).

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 14.04 you can install `ruby2.0` package. Currently the package offers version 2.0.0p384 (eventually the package might offer Ruby 2.1 or newer). This is the simples way how to install ruby binaries:

```
sudo apt install ruby2.0
```

Then you'll have binaries `ruby2.0` and `gem2.0`. For replacing default ruby 1.9 by 2.0 you can do following (**NOTE:** you might break applications that strictly requires Ruby <= 1.9).

```
sudo update-alternatives --set /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --set /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/bin/gem2.0 10
```

Other possibilities are using some ruby version manager like [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) or [RVM](http://rvm.io/). The first one is more complicated to setup, but less hacky than RVM. Both allow install almost any version of Ruby you would like to use.

Comment: Are you sure --install switch is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1892889/525174 answer helped me, but only difference is uses --set switch.

Comment: @Tombart there's an error in your code.

Comment: @horaceT Could you be more specific? Are you sure you're using **the same** Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Tombart I copied and pasted your first line. Here is the error : `update-alternatives: error: alternative name (/usr/bin/ruby) must not contain '/' and spaces` I have ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

If you’re using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) or newer then you can add this PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install whichever package you want, for example

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2
```

To be able to build native extensions you'll need to dev package too

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
```

To easily switch between installed Ruby versions, install ruby switch:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-switch
```

Commands of utiliy

```
ruby -v
ruby-switch --list
```

Example

```
sudo ruby-switch --set ruby2.1
```

From:  https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/